# Appending DataTables to an XML file

Tags: c#

I need to write multiple `DataTable`s to an XML file.

Once I write a `DataTable` to an XML file, after that the second `DataTable` is overwriting the XML file.

Is there any append method so that I can append multiple `DataTable`s to a single XML file??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataSet.GetXml() method gives xml string - you could have use that to append to file but resulting xml file would be invalid.

Does your dataset schema is same? In such case, you can merge data from datasets together and then write the combined data into an xml file.